# find time windows by conditional values in a time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a very long time series. The timestamps are equidistant. For simplicity, I am leaving out many columns and rows:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(time = c(seq(0, 2, by = 0.1)),
                   value1 = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1),
                   value2 = c(8, 7, 7, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 8, 4, 1, 2))
```

The graph of the data look likes this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value1), color = "red", size = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value2), color = "blue", size = 2)
```

[image]

Now I want to find to find the time series windows, that fulfill specific conditions. All conditions have to be met at the same time window. In this example:

- the red line (`value1`) must be between 1 and 3
- the blue line (`value2`) must be between 6 and 8
- the time window must have a length of AT LEAST 0.5 seconds. (for example: if there is a timeline of 2 seconds, where the value conditions are met, the timeline of 2 seconds should be returned an NOT 4 x 0.5 seconds timelines)

How am I able to implement this in R for a very long time series and multiple columns/conditions?
The goal is to find similar patterns in my data by a special set of conditions.

Comment: Are the timestamps equidistant, meaning I can infer the time distance from the number of timestamps (eg. every timestamp is 0.1s after the other)? Or are the timestamps more irregular?

Comment: the timestamps are equidistant!

Comment: If i say, have a timeline of 2 seconds, where the value conditions are met, how many windows should be returned? One of 2 seconds or four of 0.5 seconds?

Comment: I would say the one of 2 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this solution. It defines a `window_id` for every valid timestamp in a window. if a timestamp is not part of a valid window, `window_id` is `NA`.

```r
# value constraints
dt$value_cons_met <- inrange(dt$value1,1,3) & inrange(dt$value2,6,8)

# assign all potential sequential true timestamps a group id
dt$potential_win_id <- c(0,cumsum(abs(diff(dt$value_cons_met))))

# is the window big enough?
dt[,window_size_okay := max(time)-min(time) >= 0.5 ,by = potential_win_id]
# Other window dependent constraints can be put here

# Window "ID" is defined if the valid cons are met and window size is okay
# in that case copy potential window number as window id
dt[,window_id := ifelse(value_cons_met & window_size_okay, potential_win_id,NA)]


# sample plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value1), color = "red", size = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value2), color = "blue", size = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = window_id), color = "green", size =2)
```

This is an example plot where the detected window_id is the y value

[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution! Is there an easy way to handle NAs? If there is an NA for `value1` at, lets say 0.3 seconds, the algorithm is not working anymore. I am not able handle this with `inrange` or `between`. NAs should also be consided as `TRUE` in this case.

Comment: `inrange` assumes `NA`  as `FALSE`. It is up to your definition, wether Value constraints are kept if the Value is 'NA'. If you want to define `NA` -> `TRUE` in accordance with the value constrains just change for example constraint for value 1 from `inrange(dt$value1,1,3)` to `ifelse(is.na(dt$value1),TRUE,inrange(dt$value1,1,3))`